# Create missing .htaccess file in wordpress and add the default wordpress .htaccess rewrite rule in it

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am stuck in a difficult situation here

I have hundreds of addon and subdomains under my "public_html" having WordPress instances inside them. While cleaning up the malware, I have removed the .htaccess files from these several WordPress instances.

now, I am looking for some help here to add back the default .htaccess file and its code for such WordPress instances in one command

is that possible?

Comment: Just setup a fresh installation and copy the configuration it creates ...

Comment: Step 1: https://www.google.com/search?q=default+wordpress+htaccess
Step 2: First result has what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the default .htaccess file into `~/public_html/default.htaccess` and then use this script to copy it into any WordPress subdirectory that doesn't have a .htaccess file already:

```sh
cd ~/public_html
for dir in `ls -F | grep /`
do
  if [ ! -e "$dir/.htaccess" ] && [ -e "$dir/wp-config.php" ]
  then
    cp -v default.htaccess "$dir/.htaccess"
  fi
done
```

It could even be run as a one-liner:

```sh
cd ~/public_html; for dir in `ls -F | grep /`; do if [ ! -e "$dir/.htaccess" ] && [ -e "$dir/wp-config.php" ]; then cp -v default.htaccess "$dir/.htaccess"; fi; done
```

Comment: sorry was on a long leave... the code you provided just puts .htaccess file inside each sub folder...  I just want them to be inside subfolders having wordpress already installed... can we pass any check for this? like if there is a wp-config.php file inside the folder only then put the .htaccess file in that folder?  ....

Comment: I edited the answer to add a check for wp-config so that it only copies the file into subdirectories with WordPress.